# uniapp: [plugin:uni:mp-main-js] Cannot find module 'appSettings' from 'main.ts'

Tags: typescript, vue.js, uniapp

I'm new to vue, uniapp, ts... and the error says:
[plugin:uni:mp-main-js] Cannot find module 'W:/MiniApps/UniXmz/src/types/appSettings' from 'W:/MiniApps/UniXmz/src/main.ts'

I'm really confused by it. Is the first appSettings a type? Why "export const appSettings" is not the module it is trying to find?

main.ts:

```
import { UserOptions, AppSettings } from '@/types/appSettings'
export const appSettings = ref(new AppSettings())

const getAppSettingsData = async (appId: string) => {
const res = await getAppSettingsApi(appId, baseUrl) // baseUrl is undefined if not passed. Why? But the other apis work fine.
appSettings.value = res
console.log('after getAppSettingsData and appSetttings is ' + appSettings.value)
}
```

And yes there is a "W:/MiniApps/UniXmz/src/types/appSettings":

```
export class AppSettings {
  id: string
  appName: string
  homeOptions: HomeOptions
  topicOptions: TopicOptions
  capabilityOptions: CapabilityOptions
  mediaFileName2Urls: Map<string, string>
  userOptions: UserOptions
}
```

Any tip will be appreciated, thanks.